# SQL request using left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

**Table A :** (id, type, ...)

here id is a primary key

**Table B :** (id, timestamp, old_type, new_type, ...)

here id is not a primary key

I want to make an sql request that return such ids each with A.type not the same as the last (by timestamp) B.new_type.

Comment: Its helpful to give some context to your question. Calling things `A` and `B` makes it harder for us to understand your problem.

Comment: Please show sample data and output. Or else create sql fiddle

Comment: your question lacks information. how do we group table B?

Comment: Is B a log of changes to A?

Comment: And which RDBMS (SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle, etc) are you using? (The answer is likely to be directly relevant to how the query is written.)

Comment: Please post sql fiddle

Comment: I'm not sure whar sql fiddle is. Do you mean sql schema?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ is a website where you can post sample DDL, data and SQL queries for use on sites like StackOverflow - more here: http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html

Comment: see this link. I have created Table A. you create rest and send the link from that page to us. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f002

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful to you Nikita?

```
select a.* from A a where a.type!= (
     select b.new_type from B b order by `timestamp` desc limit 1
)
```

Comment: Thank you I 've just added A.id = B.id in brackets. But now it works very slowly(

Comment: :) You are welcome.. I would update my answer to solve your question, but I have to leave now, I will give you proper query tomorrow.. But I think you will get your answer your self before that, best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select a.id, a.type
from A a
join (select id, max(`timestamp`) max_timestamp from B group by id) mb
  on a.id = mb.id
join B b on mb.id = b.id and mb.max_timestamp = b.`timestamp`
where a.type <> b.new_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Triggers to log events, some thing like this (untested code):

```
CREATE TRIGGER logger BEFORE UPDATE ON A
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.Type <> OLD.Type THEN
    INSER INTO B(id, timestamp, old_type, new_type, ...) 
      VALUES (id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, OLD.Type, NEW.Type, ...)
  END IF;        
END;
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for further reading.